# How to avoid recompile all the files in Xcode4?

Tags: iphone, xcode4

when i change only one .m file and try to rebuild the target,
xcode 4 always recompile all the .m files.
I try to find the option to disable this feature, i want to only recompile this changed .m file and 
link all the other .o file to the target.

Answer (score 0):

why do you need that? It must be compile all file because of #import "AnotherClass.h" and other frameworks... I dont understand whats is the negative effect of this condition :) Also on XCode-4 built in syntax-error open if you write something wrongly error & warnings shows up you dont need to build..

Comment: why? even i have #import "anotherClass.h" file, if the anotherClass.m  does not changed, the anotherClass.o should not be recompiled.
Because it cost time when I debug the code

Comment: Ok forget the #import issue ,as I said before already xcode4 automatically build your.m file when you write a code in same time :) I don't understand what you need more :)

Answer (score -1):

No, Xcode does not recompile untouched files - except if you do a "clean" or if you change a bit in one of the included files. Anyway, if your files are not too big - it's not an issue anyway. ps I had a project with more than 300k lines in XCode, and files with about 30-40k. Even that size is manageable. So I would not really worry...

Comment: yes,it should not recompile, but i really do not untouch files manually. So some setting may be wrong.

Comment: It should not, but it still does. And 300k lines of code? 30k on a single file? And you're telling me that recompiling all of that would not bother you? Obviously you've never had the problem, or you work in an environment where taking coffee breaks is highly encouraged. Lucky you.